# How can I examine Quicktime file internals?

Tags: codec, quicktime

How can I examine a QuickTime file: is there a standard utility?  Or passable third party utilities?

I'd like to be able to try to debug these problems myself before resorting to "randomly install all the codecs you can find."

I use Adobe Premiere (I'm on 5) and using OSX 10.8.5 .

Example:
I'm having a problem similar to the (unanswered) one in [Can't import some .mov files into Adobe Premiere, it says “Codec missing or unavailable”](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8189/cant-import-some-mov-files-into-adobe-premiere-it-says-codec-missing-or-unav):

> Adobe Premiere 5 says "codec missing or unavailable" when trying to
>   import a .mov file… but the .mov file plays fine in Quicktime.

Comment: UPDATE: the root cause of this is the file was generated by Final Cut Pro, which wrote it with a Apple Intermediate Codec (AIC) - specifically "hdv2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The go-to tool of my choice is [MediaInfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download). It's multi plattform, open-source and can analyze a big deal of formats out there, including QuickTime. So far I barley found an unsupported format. You'll get a lot of very usefull information for debugging format issues from this tool.